# Symfony2: Do I need to create mapping-information for FOSUserBundle's abstract User class? Why are there no annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am extending from FOSUserBundle's abstract [`User`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php) class as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#a-doctrine-orm-user-class).

I see that there Doctrine/ORM's mapping-annotations in the class.

Does this mean that - if I extend from the class - the properties defined in the abstract class won't get persisted?

Do I need to manually edit the bundle's abstract class or has the mapping been defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOSUserBundle uses XML mappings.

That's the reason there are no annotations in the abstract `User` class.

- doctrine mappings can be found in [Resources/config/doctrine](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/doctrine).
- propel schema can be found in [Resources/config/propel](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/propel).

Comment: Can i make the new class from that xml file. i want to create new abstract class from that xml mapping

Comment: What do you mean by "new class". Do you want to map your extra-fields in your `User` class that extends FOSUserBundle's abstract User?

Comment: ACtually Fos User has bunch of fields which i want to hide from the views. So rather than adding annotation in that class . i will copy that Abstract class ans then extend new class from that newly Abstract classs so that i can control it. there is command here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html `orm:convert-mapping` but dont know how can i use it for single class

Comment: Don't quite understand your plans. Which fields do you want to hide from which "*views*"? Do you want to rename columns in the users-table?

Comment: Full Story is I am using JMS serializer to generate forms , which serializes the feilds i annotate with groups so that different fields are avaiable in different web pages or views. This works fine for my other classes as i can use JMS annotations. now suppose i want to only show `username, email` then i have to Exclude other fields in the `FOS User` class which i can't do as it resides in different bundle. so i ahve to copy that file and put in my Entity folder and then use that. is that ok

Comment: Again - that's a different question :) Actually it's two questions ... Either: How to hide a superclass's fields when serializing the inheriting class with JMSSerializer ? ... Or: How to create a User class for FOSUserBundle that doesn't inherit from the bundle's abstract `User` (has it's own - non-inherited - doctrine/propel/jmsserializer classmetadata) ?

Comment: Thats ok , iwill try that if get stcuk then i will ask new question